# making a commandline alias to a python file in a pipenv project

Tags: python, aliases, pipenv

I've been making a python project using pipenv, and I want to be able to run it in a terminal from any location on my (linux) system.
Specifically, say I have the following directory structure:

```
/home
  /project
    Pipfile
    main.py
  /other_dir
```

I would like to be able to make an alias that allows me to call `main.py` like so:

```
 /home/other_dir$ alias_to_my_proyect --some args
```

and run it in the virtual env, having the same behaviour as

```
/home/project$ pipenv run python main.py
```

But in another directory.

If it weren't a pipenv project, I'd just use a shebang a the start of the file and then add an alias to it in my .bashrc, but I want to use pipenv's virtual environment, but I cant find a way to do this with pipenv.

Comment: Can you edit main.py and add: `#!/usr/bin/env pipenv run python` then make main.py executable and call it directly?

Comment: @match I get `/usr/bin/env: ‘pipenv run python’: No such file or directory `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a specific python environment for your script you will need to point it to the interpreter of that environment. On Mac the default is that `pipenv` installs all virtualenvs to `/Users/<user_name>/.local/share/virtualenvs/` however that can be set to different locations as [described in the manual](http://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-virtual-environment-location):

> Pipenv automatically honors the WORKON_HOME environment variable, if you have it set — so you can tell pipenv to store your virtual environments wherever you want, e.g.:
>
> `export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs`
>
> In addition, you can also have Pipenv stick the virtualenv in project/.venv by setting the PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT environment variable.

You can find out where the exact location of the virtualenv is with `pipenv --venv` inside your project folder. It returns something like `/Users/reedef/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-BpR9WgCa`. The interpreter is in `./bin/python` of that location.

If we assume that you did not set any environment variable and you are using Mac than that means that you can write a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
/Users/reedef/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-BpR9WgCa/bin/python /home/project/main.py
```

and place it somewhere in your $PATH, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/my_fancy_main` to let it run in that specific environment.

Note: as mentioned by @Jon in the comments, `-BpR9WgCa` at the end of the path is stable as it [is made from the project path](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/dfa1dceb6399ac695cb5001d3010214e84303533/pipenv/project.py#L310):

> ```
> hash = hashlib.sha256(location.encode()).digest()[:6]
> ```

It should be the same as long as the project path hasn't changed.

Comment: As far as I know, the hash is stable as it is made from the project path. It should be the same as long as the project path hasn't changed. [source](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/dfa1dceb6399ac695cb5001d3010214e84303533/pipenv/project.py#L310)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
#!/usr/bin/env pipenv-shebang
```

in your script after you install my [pipenv-shebang](https://github.com/laktak/pipenv-shebang) package:

```
pip install pipenv-shebang
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to [write a `setup.py` file](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html).  In particular you can [write an `entry_points` section](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) that names your main script:

```
entry_points={
  'console_scripts': [
    'alias_to_my_project = project.main.main'
  ]
}
```

Once you've done this, you can activate and install your package into your virtual environment

```
pipenv install -e .

# or without pipenv
. ~/vpy/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

This will create a wrapper script in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/alias_to_my_project` that loads the `project.main` Python module and calls its `main` function.

**The wrapper script knows about the virtual environment and can be called directly** without specifically activating the virtual environment.  So you can do something like

```sh
ln -s $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/alias_to_my_project $HOME/bin/alias_to_my_project
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and it will always be available.