# Running pipenv environment via $PATH symlink to executable .py file

Tags: python, symlink, shebang, pipenv

I have a Python app that I use locally that needs to be launched via `pipenv run python3 appname.py` in order to load virtual environment with installed dependencies. This is all on macOS.

What I want to achieve is to be able to run this app from anywhere with `$ appname [args]`.

So what I did was:

- add `#!/usr/bin/env pipenv run python3` to `appname.py`;
- make that file executable with `chmod +x appname.py`;
- make symlink with `ln -s /path/to/appname.py ~/.bin/appname`;
- put `~/.bin` on my `$PATH`.

Now when I launch `$ appname`, `pipenv` creates a new virtual environment in the `~/.bin` folder and complains about missing dependencies, all instead of following through into the actual location of the script.

Is there a way to overcome this? Or maybe a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Note that `#!/usr/bin/env pipenv run python3` will run `env "pipenv run python3"` meaning those arguments will be passed a single string to `/usr/bin/env`. You can only use _a single_ argument in the shebang line

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171701/52817

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes a more sensible thing to do was freezing my code by packaging it (along with all dependencies) into an executable with `pyinstaller`.

What I did was:

1. Installed `pyinstaller` as `dev` dependency with `pipenv install --dev pyinstaller`;
2. Launched `pipenv shell` in the project directory;
3. Packaged the app with `pyinstaller --onefile appname.py`;
4. Moved the resulting self-containing `[project path]/dist/appname` executable into my `~/.bin` directory.

There were some unrelated issues to overcome, but otherwise worked perfectly for me.